# How to create ListView with two (or more) sections and types of item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Just like ListView in that Navigation Drawer:

[image]

Am I need to create three item-types for my custom adapter (Item with icon, separator item, item withhout icon), or I can achieve this in a simpler way?
Maybe I should to use two ListViews?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very similar question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At **first** use [ViewHolder](http://optimizationtricks.blogspot.com/2014/01/tricks-to-boost-performance-of-list-view.html) pattern.

At **second** make `interfase` of `Item` which will include two methods:

- `getType()` - which return the type of your item;
- `getView(LayoutInflater inflater, View convertView)` - which return the view of row. Inside this method create `ViewHolder` instance, then inflate `View` parameter to `VH` and do some action with result view.

. Then create 2 (or how much u need) classes which would implement `Item`. Define methods. Then in `ListAdapter` in `getView()` call `getView()` of items and return it to list.

And don`t use 2`ListView`. Always try to write pure code.

Answer (score 0):

**udenfox** follow this tutorial:

http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

I'm sure u'll get what you want.

Comment: No. Its how to build NavigationDrawer. My question about listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the new recyclerview and the recyclerview adapter, which allows you to do that override the getItem method and return different items for different positions , also override getItemViewType and return differrent layouts for any position.

Answer (score 0):

Pass A flag into your getview , This may not be the most efficient way i can currently think of but im pretty sure it will be of help.

A recyclerview is a really good option.

But ,

lets try to do the job with existing stuff just in case.

The following is just an example , it may not be what you want . You should look into it and grasp how it's done and implement it yourself.

**Firstly how many types of list items are you gonna have ?**
- let's take 3 for now.

**Now Pass an integer value for each type of list item in your getview method either it goes in an array type or while parsing , for example you can have an if statement in your getview method which checks the int value in a given array item and inflates a different view depending on that value.**

EXAMPLE CODE :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {
    // Declare Variables Globally , (here temporarily for answer)

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;  // arraylist passed to custom adapter in my case 

    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>(); // just a new hashmap which stores individual items from above arraylist

    result = data.get(position);

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   if(result.get("type")==1){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type1, parent, false);

    //declare variables in your view , lets take some textview
    textview.setText(result.get("something"));

    return v;

   }else if(result.get("type")==2){
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type2, parent, false);

   //take an image for example here
   imageview.displayimagewithurl(result.get(url));
    return v;

   }else{ //type 3
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.type3, parent, false);
   //in here lets take a layout with a textview and an image
    //You know what to do ..
   return v;
   }
}
```

Comment: Note : I haven't checked it's efficiency yet , this is just a getworkdonefast method without any real logic , i suggest you take on the recyclerview if your very serious although this should do for a small scale application.